# Turning entire page by 90° degrees

Tags: formatting, rotating

what is there a way to turn the page by 90 degrees?

I know there is a package called lscape, but that only rotates the content of the page, instead of the entire paper.

Basically, I imagine it like this.

[image]

So, I want to rotate the entire a4 paper by 90 degrees.

Comment: that's basically what `lscape` does, perhaps you are looking for `pdflscape` which does the same thing at the tex level but gives instructions to the viewer to change the default view of the rotated page.

Comment: Do you want the page number as shown? If so, then you *only* want the contents rotated and not the entire page. For that, look at the `rotating` package. But I'm not sure you can then tell the viewer to rotate the page automatically because the page itself remains in portrait - hence the page number in the footer as shown.